# Connect to a third party server (twelvedata) from my own express server through web socket connection string

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, ws, twelvedata

I want to connect to the `twelevedata` server through its provided socket connection to receive information.

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' 
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import express from 'express'

const app = express();

//setting up env
dotenv.config()

// setting up the websocket
const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://ws.twelvedata.com/v1/quotes/price?apikey=${process.env.API_KEY_TWELVEDATA}`);


const payload = {
  "action": "subscribe",
  "params": {
  "symbols": "AAPL,INFY,TRP,QQQ,IXIC,EUR/USD,USD/JPY,BTC/USD,ETH/BTC"
  },
}




ws.on('connection',function (steam) {

  ws.on('open', (data) => {
    console.log("data ==>",data);
    ws.emit('subscribe',payload)
  })
    
  ws.on('subscribe', (data) => {
    console.log("data ==>",data);
  })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`I am listening at ${port}`);
});
```

I created a websocket with my websocket connection on an express application but I am unable to receive any information from the twelvedata server regarding the `subscribe` event that I have emitted !

This is how the websocket should work as shown by the `twelvedata` website (look into the screen shots)

[image]
[image]

I am unable to connect and emit the `subscribe` event given by the [twelvedata's documentation](https://twelvedata.com/docs#websocket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// sending the parameters
 ws.on('open', function open() {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
  });
  
  ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    // receiving data
    console.log('data ===>: ', JSON.parse(data));
  });
```

`ws.send` did the charm for me

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to `emit` events from the websocket (that's for events you want to handle locally), but `send`, i.e., replace

```js
ws.emit('subscribe',payload)
```

with

```js
ws.send(payload)
```